# Configure a web server to get API notifications from android

Tags: android, google-chrome, firebase, server, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a back-end that is sending notifications on a android app based on a google API. I want to configure a web server where I can also receive that notification based on that API, so it wont be needed to have the phone with me all the time and I can check that notifications on my pc from web. Is this possible and how ? I heard that firebase can do that, but from what I study I don't how exactly I should do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible with [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). This requires your website to use a [service worker](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/) to [register to handle/receive push notifications in the background](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-06?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I manage to configure all of that shown in the lab, but I don't know where exactly should I add my API in order to get notifications, I manage to send myself cURL notifications via terminal, but I dont know where to go from there.

Comment: Service Worker is supported
sw.js:1 Started ServiceWorkerGlobalScope
sw.js:4 Installed ExtendableEvent
sw.js:7 Activated ExtendableEvent
main.js:12 Service Worker is ready :^) ServiceWorkerRegistration

Comment: @Rommel, in JavaScript, when you get the endpoint ID, you should send that via a POST request to your backend. Your backend needs to then save it, associated with the user. When you push to that user, you include that subscription ID as a target in FCM.